# Swiper js dont work in wordpress, javascript files not working

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, plugins, swiper.js

**The js file does not work, although it is included in the header. I don't understand how to set it up correctly.** https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI8lj.png

```
<div id="swiper-container">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <?php
                        $main = get_field('main', 7);
                        $rows = $main['slider-main'];
                        if( $rows ) {
                                foreach( $rows as $row ) {
                            echo '<div class="swiper-slide">';
                            echo '<li style="background-image: url(' .$row['slider-main-img']. ')">';
                            echo '<h3 class="slider-main-h3">' .$row['slider-main-text-h3']. '</h3>';
                            echo '<h2 class="slider-main-h2">' .$row['slider-main-text-h2']. '</h2>';
                            echo '<a href="' .$row['slider-main-href']. '" class="btn-more"> ' .$row['slider-main-text-button']. ' </a>';
                                echo '<style type="text/css"> 
                                    .btn-more { color: ' .$row['slider-main-button-collor']. ';}
                                    .slider-main-h3 { color: ' .$row['slider-main-text-h3-collor']. ';}
                                    .slider-main-h2 { color: ' .$row['slider-main-text-h2-collor']. ';}
                                </style>';
                            echo '</li>';
                            echo '</div>';
                            }
                        }
                    ?>      
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
                    <!-- Add Arrows -->
                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>  
            </div>
```

function mythem_enqueue_style() {
wp_deregister_script( 'jquery ');
wp_register_script(' jquery ', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js', false, null, true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'swiper-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/swiper-bundle.min.js', array(), true);
wp_enqueue_script( 'swiper-script-setings', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/swiper-main.js', array('swiper-script'), true);

wp_enqueue_style( 'swiper-style', get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/swiper-bundle.min.css');
wp_enqueue_style( 'style-theme', get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/style.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mythem_enqueue_style' );


.swiper-container {
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;

  }

  .swiper-slide {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: #fff;

    /* Center slide text vertically */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

Comment: Can you please give a link to check what is the exact issue?

Comment: Swiper not working on xampp, on hosting success.